# Could not create database `symfony` for connection named default

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have problem because I don't have create database

My parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

Help me, please :)

Comment: Could you @jakub-w please accept my answer if you think it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

You need to start your Mysql service,and check if the apche service is listing to 127.0.0.1.
Then just open you CLI, then type:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: You can also use `symfony console doctrine:database:drop --force`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not created directory in which you are trying to create a database.